# Passing variables to BAT file using Python subprocess.call

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

When I pass a variable to a BAT file using the following:

```
from subprocess import call
# Prompt for UID
UID = raw_input('Enter UID: ')

# Prompt for password
PSWD= raw_input('Enter your password: ')

dir = r"f:\_Python"
cmdline = "setENVvariables.bat UID, PSWD"
rc=call("start cmd /K " + cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True)
```

.. the values are not passed.  When I echo the input in the BAT file, I get the Python variable name

BAT file

```
echo %1
echo %2
```

BAT File output

```
f:\_Python>echo UID
UID

f:\_Python>echo PSWD
PSWD

f:\_Python>
```

Comment: The `PSWD` in `"setENVvariables.bat UID, PSWD"` is just the four characters "PSWD", not the variable that the user actually typed in. I am voting to close as a typo because you append strings correctly on the line immediately below.

Comment: Also, where do you expect UID to come from?

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking a shell to run start that will run a CMD to run your BAT file!

That means you want to run a subprocess, but end up starting **FOUR** instead!

- Don't use `shell=True`
- Don't use `start` unless you really need it
- Don't execute CMD

By doing this you can just pass your parameters as a list and it will work:

```
dir = r"f:\_Python"
cmdline = ["setENVvariables.bat", UID, PSWD]
rc = call(cmdline, cwd=dir)
```

Comment: given the script name (setENVvariables.bat) I doubt that this is very efficient, since if the script sets some variables, they're just lost after the script exits.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre who knows, maybe it sets some env variables before calling some program...